# Robotframework: RIDE - SikuliLibrary import error

Tags: testing, robotframework

I am working with Robotframework - SikuliLibrary for windows app testing. Everything is installed properly. From RIDE I am importing SikuliLibrary following way _

Library   SikuliLibrary

[image]

If RIDE imports properly then its text color becomes black othertwise red.
Sometimes text color is black & sometimes red. Can any one say why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some troubleshoots, you should try.

1. There is a "Import Failed Help" button on the right, below the "Variables" button.
2. As instructed in the help, you should see Tools>View RIDE Log.
3. You may right click over the failed to import library and "Import Library Spec XML" (This is mostly for Java libraries like Sikuli).

Comment: Thanks for your kind response. I have read following document.

Comment: https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE/wiki/Keyword-Completion#creating-library-specs
I am using RF 2.9.2. Do i need to add Import Library Spec XML?

Comment: FYI  today 'SikuliLibrary' is shown in black colour text in RIDE. I am getting Keyword completion help. So do I need to add Import Library Spec XML?

Comment: That looks like your problem is solved. The keywords spec are now installed in your account. If you use a different user it may not have the keywords definitions installed.

Comment: It solves automatically. But again occurs. After opening another project this problem again raised :(

Comment: I think I got the point. After opening another project it takes some time to get the Library. This is not problem actually. Am I right?

Comment: Probably is a very long project. Looks like you have the problem solved (if you are patient enough ;) )
Please accept my answer, there is nothing more to say. Thanks.