# Selenium Command not displaying - Open Browser - Robot Frameword Ride

Tags: selenium, robotframework, robotframework-ide

I have Selenium installed on my computer (3.141.0) using Python 3.7

I have imported the library to Ride to a new Suite (WebAutomation), however, after I type the keyword `OPEN BROWSER` into the test case (OpenBrowser) it is not displayed:

[image]
[image]

The keyword `OPEN BROWSER` is not included in my Selenium version?

Comment: What you apply to operate Selenium? Is in pythonic lib or is it [SeleniumLibrary](https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html) for a Robotframework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the latest version of SeleniumLibrary, 4.4.0, generates a documentation XML with some incompatibility with RIDE. There may be a long list of errors in the Parser log. We have an attempt of a workaround on the FAQ of the project page at https://github.com/robotframework/RIDE.

Answer (score 3):

Hard to say, you don't include enough information for us to help you resolve your problem.

In general, the problem will be somewhere around one of these:

- you have forgotten to install some library or dependency; please refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608831/robot-framework-selenium-library-import-issue-on-ride-python-3-7/62608899#62608899), it might be similar to your problem; in short, you need to install:

```
$ pip install -U selenium
$ pip install -U robotframework-seleniumlibrary
$ pip install -U robotframework
```

- you do not import `SeleniumLibrary`; make sure your file has this import correctly:

```
*** Settings ***
Library    SeleniumLibrary
```

- it could be only a RIDE's problem, perhaps you mean it won't show you the hint when you type `Open`? But what happens when you correctly type the whole keyword and run your test? Does it fail? With what error?

Comment: Actually, I have all 3 installed and up to date. You are right, when I type the keyword `Open Browser` and I look for the hint, it does not appears. I used the url `http://www.google.com` and the alias as `Chrome`, after I run it, the error message is `No keyword with name ´Open Browser` found. I have no clue what it might be wrong

Comment: You should also see and read the log about the failed import. There's more information on how to get the log: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212315/robotframework-ride-sikulilibrary-import-error

Comment: Turned out you are right, there was an import problem, i fixed it and it worked now

Answer (score 0):

for me I had this issue when running ride as root. when I changed to a normal user it started working.